# Pyinstaller tells me he created the .exe file but I can't find it

Tags: python, python-3.5, pyinstaller

Well basically i did this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name=OrdnerErstellen --windowed "filepath"
```

And it worked out but then I copied the Path where my .exe file should be and my PC couldn't find the file. Does somebody know why?
It also didn't even create the dist folder where all these files are supposed to go...

Im really new to programming and I just wanted to try it out :)

*EDIT: PyInstaller did make a compiled .pyc file for the one I wanted, but didn't create the .exe*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple navigate to the folder where you kept **your_script.py** file , From there run on console **pyinstaller --onefile your_script.py**

Comment: Thank you :D That was easy i guess i just did it wrong